# Text speech software for flash presentation

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, text-to-speech, presentation, voice-recording

Hello Everyone,

I have made so many Flash presentations, but every time i stuck on one part. I need to get a professional vocal audio added to my presentation. So that when a slide is running its explanation can be done vocally.

I have seen this on a website [Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/), here in the flash presentation on the very first page, someone is speaking about the content (This voice i have heard so many times on different presentations),

**My Question is:- Is that a computer generated voice or a software made voice or just someone speaking himself and recorded.**

If it is from a software can somebody help me to find it out, please :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this - http://www.naturalreaders.com/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are few famous computer talking people, like Windows Sam or Hatsune Miku (aka vocaloid, a Japanese synthesized singer girl voice). The phenomena itself is often referred to as "text to speech".

I believe that MDM Zinc provided text-to-speech for the Flash-based presentations, but it was very long ago the last time I looked into their API. It is for desktops only, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but if you can help me find any professional software which can do this for me. Let it be commercial.